# How can I align an image to the right side of a StackPanel in a WPF ListView using XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I don´t know how to make an image to the right site in a listview in an wpf app. I´m learning wpf right now for 2-3 weeks and am programming since 9 months. So please help and thanks already.

I was trying to make the second image on the right side but i couldn´t do it. I already tried horizontalalignment="right" but nothing happened.

This is my code right now.

```
<Window x:Class="list_view_test_2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:list_view_test_2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
   
   <Grid>
        <ListView SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
            <ListViewItem>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="20" Source="/WarnIcon.jpg"/>
                    <TextBlock Height="20" Width="5" Text=""/>
                    <TextBlock Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Welches threat mit Datenbank (Datei...)"/>
                    <TextBlock Height="20" Width="9" Text=""/>
                    <TextBlock Height="20" FontSize="8" Text="12:00 01.01.1999"/>
                    <TextBlock Height="20" Width="435" Text=""/>
                    <Image Height="20" Source="/info_button.jpg"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ListViewItem>
       </ListView>
   </Grid>
```

Comment: StackPanel won't do that. Use a different Panel, e.g. a Grid. Also make sure to set the HorizontalAlignment property of the ListViewItem to Stretch.

Comment: Besides that, you would not use a ListView like this. ListViewItems should not be added explicitly. Instead declare a DataTemplate as the ItemTemplate of the ListView and assign a collection of data items to the ItemsSource property. Also consider using the simpler ListBox instead of ListView.

Comment: As Clemens said. I recommend you Bind a collection of item viewmodels and template into ui. Using a gridview in your listview would allow you to line textblocks up in columns. Another option is a datagrid.  I think Setting HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" would make your items fill the width horizontally.